# Create new UserControl in popup each time popup pops

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls, popup

I have a usercontrol that has a popup that displays another usercontrol when the user selects an item from a listbox.
When the parent initializes, all the usercontrols initialize.

```
    <Popup x:Name="PopContactLogs" Width="670" StaysOpen="True" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Fade" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PageCustomerHome}" Placement="Center">
        <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="DimGray" BorderThickness="2" Background="White">
            <StackPanel>
                <DockPanel Width="1180" Background="Gray">
                    <TextBlock Text="Customer Contact Logs" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Button Name="cmdContactLogsClose" Content="X" Width="20" Foreground="Gainsboro" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                </DockPanel>
                <l:cCustomerContactLogFull x:Name="cCCLF" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

Code behind:

```
Private Sub lstContactLogs_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles lstContactLogs.MouseDoubleClick
    cCCLF = New Tracks.cCustomerContactLogFull(CustomerID, sender.selecteditem)
    PopContactLogs.IsOpen = True
End Sub
```

The problem is that the data in the observablecollection never changes from the first record that I view. I've also tried

```
Private Sub lstContactLogs_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles lstContactLogs.MouseDoubleClick
    cCCLF.CustomerID = CustomerID
    cCCLF.ContactLog = sender.selecteditem
    PopContactLogs.IsOpen = True
End Sub
```

and it just keeps the original data in there. 
I'd really like to just reinitalize it every time and basically have a new webpart each time.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Are you saying that the UserControl inside the popup isn't changing when you change selected item in the ListBox?

Comment: Well, kinda. The usercontrol has an observable collection that gets filled when the control is initialized. When you click on the second item, it doesn't reinitialize the control. When I changed it to fill with the OnLoad event I got some inconsistent errors where sometimes it would work right and sometimes it wouldn't. So I was hoping to discard it and reinitialize it fresh every time.

Comment: OK, I think I have a aolution for you now and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your template so that cCCLF isn't part of it.  Instead, replace it with a <Grid x:Name="cCCLFGrid"/>.  In your code behind, when you want to create a new cCCLF control, call cCCLFGrid.Children.Clear, create a new cCCLF, then call cCCLFGrid.Children.Add(cCCLF) that you just created.  That guarantees the removal of the old and addition of the new cCCLF.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `Instead, replace it with a *gridview*. In your code`. But that sounds like it could work well, and not to difficult to pull off at least.

Comment: You could also use a GridView to replace cCCLF, but you could use a Grid as a container for your cCCLF control.